opentelemetry-spring-boot-starter rabbitmq instrumentation
I'm using AWS Distro for OpenTelemetry and I see the following Out of the box instrumentation: https://opentelemetry.io/docs/zero-code/java/spring-boot-starter/out-of-the-box-instrumentation/
Their rabbitmq is missing. How can I add that?
I have added the following dependencies
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-bom:1.40.0"
        mavenBom "io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-instrumentation-bom:2.9.0"
    }
}

How can I add rabbitmq instumentation.

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:6.6'
    implementation 'io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-spring-boot-starter'
    runtimeOnly 'io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-log4j-context-data-2.17-autoconfigure'
    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel:1.3.5'
    implementation 'io.opentelemetry.contrib:opentelemetry-samplers:1.40.0-alpha'


    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'

    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit-test'
}

